# Is temperature correctly defined in this animation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, simulations

I saw this [animation site for gas laws](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/gases-intro/latest/gases-intro_en.html). I have some problems with it.

When I set the number of particles as 7 keeping nothing constant, the temperature was $341\;K$ and pressure $0.9$ atm. When I reduced it to 5, the temperature reading was $385\;K$ and pressure $0.5$ atm, when 3 it was $289\; K$ with pressure $0.3$ atm and when 1 it was $20\;K$ and pressure $0$ atm.

I know that most of us wil not get same result but give it a try if you doubt my observation.

I would like to know why is the temperature changing with such randomness while pressure is having a regular change (as expected) ? Is there a physical reason for that ?

Comment: I have taken screenshots too if someone needs a proof please comment..

Comment: Your animation doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: @Bob D  really !!! I could open it using the same link btw.. it is the Phet animations..

Comment: @BobD Works for me... Might be a browser thing? I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temperature and pressure are ultimately statistical properties of a large number of particles.  Asking for the temperature - or pressure - of a single atom is meaningless.

In the case of an ideal gas, it turns out that temperature can be related to the average kinetic energy of the gas molecules via the equipartition theorem, which yields ${KE}_{av} = \frac{3}{2}kT$ where $k$ is the Boltzmann constant.  Inverting this relation gives $T = \frac{2}{3k} KE_{av}$.  This is how the simulation you mention defines temperature.

When you insert particles into the simulation, they are created with an energy which corresponds to the temperature displayed at the top of the screen.  When they collide with one another, they randomly exchange energy, and so very quickly all of the particles have randomized energies while keeping the same average. When you subtract particles from the simulation, it simply deletes a particle which is already present.  If the number of particles is large, then deleting one or two particles doesn't affect the average very much, but if the number of particles is small, deleting one particle could have a large effect on the average (and therefore the displayed temperature).

Similarly, the pressure (via the ideal gas law) is $P = \frac{NkT}{V}$.  From the volume of the box, the temperature, and the number of particles, the pressure can be calculated.  Since this depends on the total particle kinetic energy ($\propto NT$), it will suffer the same issues when the number of particles is small; even though the total pressure will always decrease when removing particles from the simulation, the amount by which it decreases will be random for the same reason as above.

Comment: do you mean that the kinetic energy of each new particle is not the same ?

Comment: @Ankit Yes, that’s right. They’re selected randomly from a distribution. You can choose their *average* temperature, but each individual energy is different.

Comment: so is this randomness in energy the cause of sudden increase or decrease in temperature ?

Comment: @Ankit If you read my answer, the temperature in the simulation is **defined** by the average kinetic energy of the particles which are present. If you have 4 particles and take one away, that’s going to significantly change the average. This wouldn’t happen if you had 100 particles, for example.

Comment: @Ankit You can't define a property like temperature for a small number of particles (certainly not 7!) Such a quantity becomes defined only in the [thermodynamic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit).

Comment: @Ankit - When particles are added, they have the same energy - The energy corresponding to that temperature. As they collide, some gain energy and some lose it. The total energy stays the same, and therefore so does the average energy. But when particles are removed, some particle is chosen. If it has more energy than the average, the average energy of the remaining particles drops. The temperature drops. If it had happened that a slower than average particle was removed, the average energy would have been higher, and the temperature of the remaining particles would have been higher.

Comment: @mmesser314 Thanks for that - a mistake on my part.  I played with this simulation a long time ago and worked these things out, but apparently misremembered in the meantime.

Comment: @mmesser314 so are you saying that the initial energies of each particle is same ? And it changes only after collision ?

Comment: @Ankit My mistake - as per mmesser314's comment, the particles are all *created* with the same energy, and then randomly exchange energy during collisions.  The main point - that subtracting individual particles can drastically change the average if the number of particles is small - stays the same.

Comment: @J. Murray but collision is perfectly elastic . Isn't it ?

Comment: @Ankit - Yes. You can see that in the simulation. All the particles enter at the same speed.

Comment: @Ankit Energy can be exchanged between particles in perfectly elastic collisions.  The total kinetic energy is the same, but one particle gains energy while the other loses the same amount.

Comment: @mmesser314 so isn't the collision perfectly elastic ?

Comment: @Ankit - As J.Murray said, yes they are perfectly elastic.

Comment: @J. Murray I didn't notice the same issue with pressure. By decreasing mole ules the pressure also decreased while temperature increased ?

Comment: @Ankit The pressure is proportional to the **total** KE in the system.  Decreasing the particle number will always decrease the pressure, but the amount by which the pressure decreases is random for the same reason that the change in temperature is random. I've clarified this in my answer.